# Is there a CMS similar to Drupal with a rule engine editor and workflow task manager included?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, workflow, drools, rule-engine

I'm looking to develop a website that collects information that a user provides about their company, analyzes it based on industry trends I've saved into the system, and does something based on the information received (i.e. make recommendations, creates reports, sends out emails, and/or asks the user additional questions) using my industry knowledge. In addition to needing a rule engine to to provide information back to a user, I also will need to initiate workflow tasks that are assigned to my employees, vendors, or back to the user based on the rule engine logic.

I understand the business logic behind my idea, and how to use content management systems such as drupal. However, I'm not sure how to integrate my business logic, rules based on external market trends, and workflow technology into a content management system I can update as things change.  I am looking for a solution that has a user interface to allow me to update the questions required (such as editing content types in Drupal), update my consultative knowledge database, and update the rules on how to apply them without having to hire a programmer when the business landscape changes.

In my research, I understand drupal rules module is not a true rete rules engine - so I don't believe I can use.

The concept of combining Drupal's content types (for collecting user information and editing fields), Jboss Drools' rule engine (for creating rules), and salesforce.com's  workflow editor (for creating and assigning workflow tasks) is what I'm looking for.  **Is there anything out there that brings all of this together, in one web based user/admin solution that can be set up and used similar to Drupal's UI experience?**  In addition, am I even on the right track as far as the best way accomplish?

Comment: I've been monitoring the Drools user list for several years and I've never heard about anything like what you're asking - a name like Drupal would have stuck. Connections to DBs were mentioned frequently enough to stay in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module is the de-facto standard Drupal rule engine. Could you elaborate about how it is not fit for your tasks.

A lot of contrib module supports it out of the box (ie. they provide new actions, event types, etc.). The [Maestro](https://drupal.org/project/maestro) module provides a generic workflow engine, with support for various tasks.